# Authenticate Client certificate and get response from server

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am working on get data from client server(ratin24 API). The API basically work after Authentication means I have one certificate and I was authenticate it with NSURLSession "didReceiveChallenge" delegate method. Everything is working fine but now issue is that I Got only header parts as a response not BOTY. so how to get actual data from there. I Pass XML Parameter in request body and the response should be XML but Got only header so please help me how to get BODY data in this situation.

```
let xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><TICKETANYWHERE><COUPON VER='1.0'><TEMPLATELIST /></COUPON></TICKETANYWHERE>"
let xmlData = xmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "My URL")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = xmlData
request.addValue("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
struct SessionProperties {
    static let identifier : String! = "url_session_background_download"
}


let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let backgroundSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate:self as? NSURLSessionDelegate, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

let downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTaskWithRequest(request){ (data, response, error) -> Void in
            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")
            }


        }
        downloadTask.resume()
```

Response Data (only Header) body ? :

```
status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 23113;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
    Date = "Mon, 27 Jun 2016 11:36:12 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response object isn't supposed to contain the body data.  An NSURLResponse object contains only metadata, such as the status code and headers.  The actual body data should be in the NSData object for a data task, or in the provided file for a download task.

Note that for a download task the first parameter is an NSURL, not an NSData object.  That NSURL contains the location of a file on disk from which you must immediately read the response data in your completion handler or move the file to a permanent location.